How to give someone else your drone to fly
I got a DJI mini 3. I got my operator ID which is required for camera drone. Now my son 9yo is ahead of me as he has been flying his toy drone for 1 year and now he has his flyer ID as well.
What can I do to make sure he is flying my drone as I have my operator ID for drone but can’t have another Operator ID for same drone.
What should I do if he wanna fly my drone?

I think you are still the operator/owner. EASA has two roles: operator/owner and pilot. Confusedly often "operator" refers to the remote pilot. I doubt your son has the insurance (and financial obligations), so you are the operator. I think UK has similar rules.
